# Can I add extra list item element using css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, listitem

I am developing a website through wordpress and by default the theme has 4 list items in my flex-nav-bar (slider which slides images). Can I add one more item using css? See the flex navbar
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7Box.jpg)

and when I inspect it the HTML code is

```
<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging"><li><a href="#" class="">1</a></li><li><a href="#" class="flex-active">2</a></li><li><a href="#">3</a></li><li><a href="#">4</a></li></ol>
```

Here, there are 4 list items, can I add one more using css? or any other methods. Please suggest.Thanks.

Comment: You would need to use vanilla JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Look in to the `.appendChild()` function in JavaScript. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp